# Elasticsearch fails to map imported data

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have managed to create an import from Kafka to Elasticsearch using Kafka Connect. 
**Connector-config**:

```
{
 "name": "raw-customer-equipment", 
 "config": { 
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector", 
  "tasks.max": 1, 
  "topics": "raw.customer.equipment", 
  "key.ignore": true, 
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": false, 
  "schema.ignore": true, 
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
  "connection.url": "<elastic-url>", 
  "connection.username": "<user>", 
  "connection.password": "<pwd>", 
  "type.name": "_doc" } 
}
```

However Elasticsearch doesnt seem to be able to map the imported (Json) data. When peeking on it in Kibana the imported data doesnt seem to be search'able.

```
{
  "_index": "raw.customer.equipment",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "raw.customer.equipment+1+929943",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "ifstats_list": [
      {
        "Event Time": "1589212678436",
        "AP_list": [
          {
            "AP ID": 1,
            "AP Alias": "PRIV0"
          },
          {
            "AP ID": 2,
            "AP Alias": "VID1"
          },
          {
            "AP ID": 5,
            "AP Alias": "VID1_BH"
          }
        ],
        "Device Type": "<type>",
        ...
    "Associated Stations": [
      {
        "Packets sent": 11056613,
        "Packets received": 304744,
        "Multiple Retries Count": 0,
        "Channel STA": 6,
        "MAC Address": "<mac>",
        ....
      },
      {
        ....
      }]
....
```

I want to be able to query by for instance "MAC Address" but Elastic seem to just handle the imported data as a big text-chunk.

I guess It is something in the Kafka-connector setup that is missing or wrong but I fail to see what.

As you might have guessed Im new at Elastic, and Im not the one supposed to be able to use the data in the end 

Any help appreciated
BR

**Edit:**
Added connector-config by request.

Comment: Please provide your Kafka Connect config

Comment: Sure - added to main post. Thought this would be a more general issue - thats why I didnt post it originaly